# How to get ExtendedMembershipProvider to work with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Custom Membership Provider?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

I have got a custom membership provider to work with ASP.NET MVC 4 but when i whant to use the OAuth logins like Facebook etc I'm getting an error:

```
To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
```

This happening when calling the function OAuthWebSecurity.Login in the ExternalLoginCallback actionresult.

I guess to get all to work I need a custom "ExtendedMembershipProvider" but I can not find any information about it, any ideas?

Comment: I find out that i needed to change the AccountController to not run the WebSecurity functions and create my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebMatrix.WebData.ExtendedMembershipProvider` class

Inherit your custom membership provider from it and implement all members you need.

Answer (score 2):

here is the sample of using ExtendedMembershipProvider 
https://github.com/mazhekin/MVC4CustomMembershipSolution